# Sudden shutdown happens only when I have PhpStorm opened

Tags: ubuntu, java, hardware, shutdown

I've had this reoccurring sudden shutdown issue happening recently, and it always happens when I have PhpStorm opened, I'm not sure if it's related, but it still seems random, meaning that sometimes I have PhpStorm opened without any sudden shutdowns.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 on Lenovo Y50-70. I've tried running stress tests to replicate this issue, but it wasn't successful, no sudden shutdowns.

I've converted from java-8-oracle to java-7-openjdk-amd64 thinking maybe the issue is related to java but it happened again.

I'm becoming more sure to admit that it's a hardware issue, but it didn't happen on Windows 8.

I'm still able to return the laptop back and replace it, but I want to make sure this is a hardware issue, and to have convincing reasons as to why I'm returning it back. I don't want them to tell me, "But it works fine on Windows so it's a software issue", so I want to make sure it's a hardware issue and know if there are any possible fix.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EdGBUSGH) is my mcelog file, it indicates that there are many reoccuring hardware errors:

Comment: I have the same error. When I'm working on Android Studio, on Ubuntu,
the laptop shuts down suddently only when is not plugged into a power supply (Battery can be arround 90% when this happens, and if I'm not using Android Studio there are no battery problems, I can spend 3 hours or more with the battery). Did you found the error? How did you solve it?

Comment: @Jeicob22 This issue still happens on Ubuntu and OpenSUSE, but I have found that when I use PHPStorm on the "Power Save Mode", this issue doesn't happen. It seems that this issue is related to IntelliJ IDEA since it's common between PhpStrom and Android Studio, also because this issue happens more often when the project is being indexed.

Answer (score 0):

The mcelog you posted suggests it's a memory issue:

> Generic CACHE Level-2 Generic Error

I suggest you test your machine's hardware using Ubuntu's memtest, you can find an entry for memtest as a menu entry when you boot your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Also happen to me. But I found a solution, I'd just install "openjdk-7-jdk", while "openjdk-7-jre" already installed using "Software Manager".

I am running PhpStorm-2016.1 build PS-145.1616.3 in linuxmint-17.3 codename "Rosa".

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the switchable graphics driver on Linux. Disabling the Nvidia adapter gets rid of this problem. I solved the issue by:

1. Enter the BIOS setup (by pressing the NOVO button while the
   computer is off)
2. Changing graphics mode to "*UMA Graphics*" instead of "*Switchable Graphics*"
3. Reboot into Linux

Obviously it would be preferable to have the nvidia adapter on. If I figure out how to get switchable graphics to work, I'll update this post.